# Entity Framework Core Multiple sub objects Include / ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble including all the entities when using EF to query. Using dummy labels, my DB has a structure of a Family which contains a Collection of Person objects, and a House. Each Person object has a Wallet associated with them, with the Wallet having a Driver's License object. The House has three objects: a Ktichen, Den, and Garage. My Models were set up with a DB-first approach and I can provide them if need be.

But I'm having a 'Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.' error when running this code:

```
public Family GetFamily(int familyId)
{
    DBContext context = new DBContext();

    Family family= context.Family.Where(fam=> fam.Id== famId)
        .Include(fam => fam.PersonCollection)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Wallet)
                .ThenInclude(w => w.License)
        .Include(fam => fam.House)
            .ThenInclude(h => h.Kitchen)
        .Include(fam => fam.House)
            .ThenInclude(h => h.Den)
        .Include(fam => fam.House)
            .ThenInclude(h => h.Garage)
        .First();

return family
}
```

If I comment out the includes for the License, and two of the three rooms in the house, it runs, but otherwise it does not.

Here are all the Models

```
public partial class Family
{
    public Family()
    {
        PersonCollection = new HashSet<PersonCollection>();
    }

    public int HouseId { get; set; }

    public virtual House House { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonCollection> PersonCollection { get; set; }
}


public partial class House
{
    public House()
    {
        Family = new HashSet<Family>();
        Den = new HashSet<Den>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte KitchenId { get; set; }
    public int? DenId { get; set; }
    public int? GarageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Kitchen Kitchen { get; set; }
    public virtual Garage GarageNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Den DenNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Family> Family{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Den> Den { get; set; }
}


public partial class Kitchen
{
    public Kitchen()
    {
        House = new HashSet<House>();
    }

    public byte Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<House> House { get; set; }
}


public partial class Garage
{
    public Garage()
    {
        House = new HashSet<House>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<House> House { get; set; }
}

public partial class Den
{
    public Den()
    {
        House = new HashSet<House>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<House> House { get; set; }
}


public partial class Person
{
    public int FamilyId{ get; set; }
    public int? WalletId { get; set; }

    public virtual Wallet Wallet { get; set; }
    public virtual Family Family { get; set; }
}

public partial class Wallet
{
    public Wallet()
    {
        PersonCollection = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? DenId { get; set; }

    public virtual License License { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; }
}


public partial class License
{
    public License()
    {
        Wallet = new HashSet<Wallet>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Wallet> Wallet { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Model Builders. I had to rename and delete a lot of things to simplify and obfuscate our code, but hopefully I kept everything that's relevant.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Family>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.House)
            .WithMany(p => p.Family)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.FamilyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Family_House");
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Wallet)
            .WithMany(p => p.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.WalletId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Person_Wallet");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Family)
            .WithMany(p => p.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.FamilyId })
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Person_Family");
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Wallet>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.LicenseNavigation)
            .WithMany(p => p.Wallet)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.License)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Wallet_License");
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<License>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("License", "DBO");
    });
            
    modelBuilder.Entity<House>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Kitchen)
            .WithMany(p => p.House)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.KitchenId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_House_Kitchen");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.GarageNavigation)
            .WithMany(p => p.House)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Garage)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_House_Garage");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.DenNavigation)
            .WithMany(p => p.House)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Garage)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_House_Garage");
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Kitchen>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Garage>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Den>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("Den", "DBO");

        entity.Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some additional information about `Licence` and `Wallet` classes, as well as `ModelBuilder` configuration of those?

Comment: I wonder why you have collections with `PersonCollection` class,  not the `Person`. Still, I  asked for `ModelBuilder` configuration as well, maybe you have missed something there

Comment: Trying to find that ModelBuilder config for you still - it was set up by another dev. I had some typos in the model where I didn't dummy up the real model names, which I fixed.

Comment: You can find ModelBuilder config in `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` class